# Using selection by expression in PyQGIS to select all features with a field that contains a string. (And help clariflying expressions in general)

Tags: python, expression, gis, qgis, pyqgis

I'm pretty new to PyQGIS, I'm a hobbyist so some things that the documentation takes for granted confuse me. For example, I know that by using the selectByExpression function I can select objects in a layer who's corresponding DBF matches a certain criteria:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression('"EXAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE"=\'example_string\'')
```

However, what if I want to do more than comparison? The PyQGIS docs define the first argument for this method as

> expression (str) – expression to evaluate to select features

So, what can I use for this expression? In the project I'm working on right now, I need to select all objects that have a field (A string representing the name) that contains a certain string. I've tried:

```
layer.selectByExpression('\'example_string\' in "EXAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE"')
```

This compiles but doesn't do what I expect it to. Can anyone clarify what exactly counts as a viable expression for this method?

EDIT:
So, I actually solved this problem by iterating over a list of all the features instead of the selectByExpression method, however I'm leaving the question open in hopes someone has a more efficient method.